# How to change a parameter in kaminari pagination - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, kaminari

My pagination works like;

```
/questions/meals/fish?page=1
```

I would like to modify the second parameter of this URL like:

```
/questions/deserts/fish?page=1
```

How can I change the second parameter? (preferably without modifying the `routes.rb` file)

Comment: Why don't you want to modify the routes file?

Comment: it's a little difficult to change it. But I'm opened to all solution ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In the kaminari `paginate` helper method you can override the controller and action

```
paginate @users, params: {controller: 'foo', action: 'bar'}
```

So in your case...

```
paginate @fishes, params: {controller: 'desserts', action: 'fish'}
```

Note that it has to be a valid route in your `routes.rb` or when the link is clicked, the app won't accept the path.